# set img src as anchor tag href attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery

am trying to append images in a div,and set their src to the selected anchor tag href,and perevent the anchor tag from opening when clicked.here is the code.the (.loader)is the divs class.

```
function born(){
        var link=$(this).attr("href")

        $(".loader").append("<img src="link" alt="sh** aint working"/>")
    return false;   

}
```

below is the html code (anchor tag href)

```
<a href="slides/alvo2.jpg" onclick="born();" ><div class="thumb"><img src="thumbs/alvo2.jpg" alt="" width="124" height="70" border="0" /></div></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of single `'` and double `"` quotes

```
$(".loader").append("<img src='" +link +" 'alt='sh** aint working'/>")
```

Also, cancel default anhcor action

```
onclick="return born();"
```

Comment: @saptal,just edited it ,not working still opening default link

Answer (score 1):

You are not cancelling the click, you are missing a return

```
onclick="return born();"
```

Also you have a quoting problem with your append.

Answer (score 0):

```
function born(){
    var link=$(this).attr("href");

    $(".loader").append("<img src='" + link + "' alt='sh** aint working'/>");
return false;
```

}